# nginx - add header's value in parameters

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add a header's value (HEADER_PARAM) in a parameter (my_param). Here's my code :

```
 location /CUSTOM_LOCATION {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?my_param=$http_header_param break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/CUSTOM_LOCATION ;
  }
```

The parameter is empty while the header `HEADER_PARAM` exists. Any idea why ?

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` to avoid `proxy_pass` possibly overriding the rewritten URI?

Comment: yes just did. The parameter is still empty. I get to `http://localhost/CUSTOM_LOCATION?access_token=&other`

Comment: I tested your `rewrite` statement using `$http_host` (just for test purposes) and it worked as expected. I don't know why it does not work with your other `$http_` parameter.

Comment: I tested it using $http_host and I didn't have the expected result. I'm going to look for the problem somewhere else in the configuration. Thanks a lot Richard